# Vuejs:How to enable select option when another select option is selected

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

im using library `vue-search-select` to disable the select option used `isDisabled`. Initially the select option on `specialty` is disabled. I want it when `hospital` is selected, then disable the `specialty` disappears.

This is my view:

[image: view]

And my code:

```
<model-list-select :list="hospital"
    v-model="optHospital"
    @change="getSpeciality"
    option-value="id"
    option-text="hospital_name"
    placeholder="Choose Hospital">
</model-list-select>

<model-list-select :list="speciality"
    isDisabled
    v-model="optSpeciality"
    @change="getDoctor"
    option-value="specialist_id"
    option-text="specialist_name"
    placeholder="Choose Speciality">
</model-list-select>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable it conditionally based on the value of the first select, for example disable it when the first select is undefined, that would be something like that:

```html
<model-list-select :list="hospital"
    v-model="optHospital"
    @change="getSpeciality"
    option-value="id"
    option-text="hospital_name"
    placeholder="Choose Hospital">
</model-list-select>

<model-list-select :list="speciality"
    :isDisabled="optHospital === undefined" // here
    v-model="optSpeciality"
    @change="getDoctor"
    option-value="specialist_id"
    option-text="specialist_name"
    placeholder="Choose Speciality">
</model-list-select>
```